# How do I add a new line of text with Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get the Text (CEO) to appear directly below the name. When I add it, it's all the way on the bottom

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 35.0)
            Image("employeeID")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.red/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
            .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.red/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                    Color.white
                    HStack {
                        Text("Jobs")
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.top, 20.0)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        Text("Steve")
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.top, 20.0)
                        .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.largeTitle/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    }
                }
                Text("CEO")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: vertical alignment]

Comment: You can debug UI and check who takes space between "Jobs Steve" and "CEO"

Comment: I am very new to SwiftUI. How do you debug? It's always compiling  and running

Comment: You can find view hierarchy by tapping button specified on screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtkjgb339bay2ks/Screenshot%202020-04-03%20at%2023.10.27.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution but I don't think I should need to add padding to the top

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 35.0)
            Image("employeeID")
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(radius: 10.0)
                .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.red/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
            .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.red/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                    Color.white
                    HStack {
                        Text("Jobs")
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        Text("Steve")
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.largeTitle/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 20.0)
                    Text("CEO")
                        .padding(.top, 60.0)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It feels like a hack rather than an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them into own VStack, like below

```
...
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Jobs")
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        Text("Steve")
            .fontWeight(.light)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.largeTitle/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
    Text("CEO") // << right below name
}
.padding(.top, 20.0) // << padding entire container
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ZStack` is a greedy `View` which means it takes all the space it is given and so it pushes `Text("CEO")` to the bottom of the screen.

You have to place a `VStack` inside your `ZStack`. It will contain the `HStack` you already have, `Text("CEO")` and add a `Spacer()` (another greedy `View`) to make sure all the `Text`s get pushed up towards the image. Your `ZStack` should look like this:

```
ZStack (alignment: .top) {
    Color.white
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Jobs")
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Steve")
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }   .padding(.top, 20.0)
        Text("CEO")
            .padding(.top, 60.0)
        Spacer()
   }
```

}